# Adjusting Font-Size of ListItem in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

What i'm trying to achieve is to loop through a list and add items to a listbox with different types of styles in an ASP.NET application. so far I've got the following code in my aspx file:

in the header:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .list .Title
        {
            font-size: x-large;
        }
        .list .Title1
        {
            color:Red;
        } 
        .list .Title2
        {
            color:Black;
        }
        .list .Title3
        {
            color:Green;
        }
         .list .Line
        {
            background-color:Black;
        }

    </style>
```

Somewhere In the body:

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="CurrentListBox" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="400" CssClass="list">   
                                </asp:ListBox>
```

In the code Behind i do this whilst looping through the list items depending on a few factors it goes through one of these:

(I work in VB.NET but an answer in CSharp will do just aswell, i'll translate it)

```
item.Attributes.Add("class", "Title")
```

or

```
item.Attributes.Add("class", "Title1")
```

or 
etc. etc. etc.

**PROBLEM:**
It does the colours and it changes it just fine. but the fontsize never changes only the colour gets through.

Maybe some extra information: it loops through this code at pageload.

Comment: why you need ".list" class? it is misleading. if you need to specify hierarchy - implement it for some parent div, but for this given control specify only Title, Title1, etc. Then you can use CssClass property instead of Attributes. if you want to apply more than one style to control - specify classes separated by " " (space)

Comment: I've based my last try on the example found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1669523.aspx/1 posted by Ming Xu - MSFT

And i've tried using the cssclass property but the font sizes still do not change

Comment: ListBox compiles into <select> (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) and its child items <option> tags do not support styles. Try to use GridView instead - it more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 CurrentListBox.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:x-large;");
```

Thanks

Comment: Still the same result i'm afraid, it takes the colours but not the fontsize.

Comment: Still the same result, only the colours change and the font-sizes stay normal.